# Cisco ASA force failover from command line

Tags: cisco-asa, failover

I have 2 independent traffic routes to my servers.  They are serviced by a failover Cisco ASA5505 pair.  However, should my gigabit switch on the main route fail (or main internet feed), the ASA will not detect this and failover to the standby route.

To get around this, I can detect failure of the active route from a server, easy enough.

Tricky bit: Can I run a console command/batch file to initiate this failover?

```
|===============|         |===============|
|   Internet    |         |   Internet    |  (No admin access, possibly not Cisco)
|    Route A    |         |    Route B    |
|===============|         |===============|
        |                         |
        |                         |
|===============|  heart  |===============|
|    ASA5505    |---------|    ASA5505    |
|===============|  beat   |===============|
        |                         |
        |                         |
|===============|         |===============|
|    Switch     |         |    Switch     |  (Not Cisco)
|===============|         |===============|
        |                         |
        |                         |
|=========================================|
|                  Server                 |
|=========================================|
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do this if you have a script with ssh capability. But much better are the ASA "Track" and "Ip SLA" options. look into those to track the route from the asa and add a SLA to that to switch over the network route.

Comment: I would vote up, but don't have the points.  I should have mentioned that the switches and internet feed are not Cisco (or at I don't have admin access), if that makes any difference.  There may also be other switches/routers up the internet chain at the data center.

Comment: the tracking and sla options in the ASA do not require other equiptment to be cisco products. one of the track options is a simple ping to and ip, if it can not be pinged the tracker switches mode. so the SLA can get active/inactive